# TypeInitalizationException C# EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013 v12. I'm having problem while running some EmguCV code, I've copied exactly the same code from the "A Basic Program" but it doesn't works, when it arrives at some line (I believe is the "Image My_Image = new Image(Openfile.FileName);" line ), it gives the TypeInitalizationException, as you can see in the print

http://oi61.tinypic.com/29gcugm.jpg

The curious point is: when i open the original example project "A basic program" and run, it works fine.

I have followed all these instructions: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp

But, just don't know what to do anymore...

I have installed emgucv 2.4.10

Thanks for now...

(Sorry about my english)

Comment: Are you referring to this [error](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp#System.TypeInitializationException:_.C2.A0Convertion_from_Image.3CEmgu.CV.Structure.Bgr.2A.2CSystem.Byte.2A.3E_to_Image.3CEmgu.CV.Structure.Structure.Bgr.2A.2CSystem.Byte.2A.3E_is_not_supported_by_OpenCV.C2.A0) ?

Comment: @dvhh is right, sounds like you are missing a DLL. If it's not obvious, which one, it might help to compare the directory listing of the working test project with that of your non-working project, to see which files you are missing.